# ASP.NET MVC | How to fire Ajax when I click in combobox in Telerik TreeView

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, telerik

I am using Telerik TreeView control. I set up it to use check boxes. When I click in combobox I want to fire Ajax request to action in controller. Then I want to reload some part page. How to fire Ajax to action by clicking in combobox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could register for the click event:

```
$(function() {
    $('#treeViewId :checkbox').click(function() {
        // when a checkbox is clicked
        // fire an AJAX request to some action
        // and refresh the contents of some div
        $('#someDiv').load('<%= Url.Action("someaction") %>');
    });
});
```